# Multi conditional assigment in pandas

Tags: pandas

How can i vectorize something like

```
if col > 1:
    col = 5
elif col < -1:
    col = 10
else:
    col = 15
```

I want to do this in pandas

```
df['col'] = ...?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.select` for this. Example below :

```
conditions = [
    (df['col'] > 1),
    (df['col'] < -1)]
choices = [5, 10]
df['col'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=15)
```